# SPL Autoload doesn't load class

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I've read answers to the same questions here at SO, but they haven't helped me to fix my problem.

I have the follows directory structure:

[image]

And this class:

```
namespace Util;

final class Autoloader
{
    public static function loader($class)
    {
        define('PHP_FILE_EXTENSION', '.php');
        $filename = '';
        $file = '';
        $phisicalFilePath = '';

        $filename = $class . PHP_FILE_EXTENSION;
        $phisicalFilePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

        if (file_exists($phisicalFilePath)) {
            require_once 'util/' . $filename;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the above class as follows from the `bootstrap.php` file:

```
require_once('util/Autoloader.php');

spl_autoload_register('Util\Autoloader::loader');
```

And I call everything from an `index.php` file:

```
require_once('bootstrap.php');

echo StringUtils::randomString(10);
```

---

But unfortunately, the SPL autoload doesn't load the class:

```
Fatal error: Class 'StringUtils' not found in 'xxx\index.php' on line 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take care: `StringUtils` !== `stringutils`

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, that was a last minute change. I'll update the picture.

Comment: you're checking existents of one file (`$phisicalFilePath`), but include another (`'back-end/util/' . $filename`)

Comment: @Lashane Yes, but I tried with `util/$filename` too, and it didn't work.

Comment: `util/$filename` is not the same as `$phisicalFilePath`

Comment: add output of `$phisicalFilePath` _before_ you call `file_exists`

Comment: @Lashane Yes, because I've readed that `file_exists` checks for the phisical path of a file. I've just to output the content of `$phisicalFilePath` and it shows the absolute path to the PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution. It might be useful if you want to continue with development in PHP.

Look at this articles - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/ and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. They contain officially approved standards regarding classes structure for PHP-based projects.

We shouldn't investigate the wheel in such cases - so try to keep in touch with "official standards" if it's possible.

---

I created example project to show how to apply mentioned rules.

Project structure:

[image: Project tree]

`Autoloader.php` was copied from here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md#class-example. The only difference is that my autoloader was placed in the namespace `Util` and its class was renamed to `Autoloader`.

Then `Account.php` contains:

```
<?php

namespace Model;

class Account { }
```

And `index.php`:

```
<?php

require_once('Util/Autoloader.php');

$autoloader = new \Util\Autoloader();
$autoloader->addNamespace('\Model\\', __DIR__ . '/Model');
$autoloader->register();

$model = new \Model\Account();
```

Comment: More a case of "recommended" by the Framework Interoperability Group, but certainly recommended for use in any application

Comment: I've just change my code to use the PSR-4 callback example and it didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @leoMestizo, wait a minute - I'll update my answer with example

Comment: It's good that you quoted "official standards". But keep in mind some day folks will realize they have been duped with trading convenience for language breakage and the most inefficient scheme of file-by-file autoloading.

Comment: @mario, I think that you are talking about current autoloading solution, that was accepted as "official standard". Rather than more deep work with PHP itself and, for example, implementation of "import" mechanism at the language level. You mean this, right?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a project as your's and copied your files contents.
it works for me.
there is no problem with your code.

Comment: That has a lot of sense... I've just to change my code to use `include` and I get the same error.

Comment: I think there is just one reason that code is working on my system and unfortunately not working on your system. check permission of your StringUtils.php file.